# What is the meaning of "as clear as a bell"?

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning “as clear as a bell”?

I met this expression long time ago but I have forgotten what it means.

Comment: Please stop puttings spaces around your punctuation.

Comment: You said "I have forgotten what it means." Have you tried looking it up? If so, please do so before asking here. If you have, then please explain where and why that didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally it refers to the fact that bells are loud and have a sound with a relative lack of overtones, giving a "clear" sound.

By simple analogy, it can refer to a sound that is similarly easily heard and easily discerned.

Stretching the analogy further, it can refer to any signal that is easily discerned (e.g. a television signal that was "clear as a bell" would result in both a faithfully reproduced sound and also a good picture).

In common figurative use, it can refer to anything easily discerned and understood, such as instructions that were in plain language and easily comprehended.

Comment: Well, bells typically have an *extended* overtone series. You could look it up. In fact, the reason woodwind and brass instruments have belled endings is to create more overtones.